# Change the background color of item in RecylerView , having position only

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have the positions for all the items in the `RecyclerView` and I want to write a code which programmatically gives background color of the item, just on the basis of position provided to it. So far I am able to scroll to the item by using this `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(Integer.parseInt(value));.` But not able to highlight or give background color to that item.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Put it into the model
2. Use a decoration

---

The first approach is straight forward. Along with the list of items your adapter knows about the highlighted position(s). Upon changes, you invalidate the list and apply your data in `onBindViewHolder`, including possible highlights.

```
onBindViewHolder(...) {
  // ...
  if (positionIsHighlighted) view.setBackground(dis) else view.setBackground(dat)
}
```

---

Another approach would be to do something similar using an [`ItemDecoration`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html). You draw on top/below any views you want to highlight. This involves custom drawing and some more knowledge than the first approach.

The benefits are that it may be more reusable and that you can draw on top or outside the boundaries of your selected views.

Comment: Thank you David for your answer. So actually i have a map on a screen with markers on it. I want that on click of the markers i should be able to highlight the item corresponding to it in the recylerview.  More over, i am accessing recylerview from some other class. So far i was just able to scroll till the item in the list. Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable in your adapter like `selectedItemPosition : Int = 0`, then have a setter like below:

```
fun setSelectedItem(position:Int){
    if(position == this.selectedItemPosition) return
    val oldPosition = this.selectedItemPosition
    this.selectedItemPosition = position
    if(oldPosition >=0 )
        notifyItemChanged(oldPosition)
    if(position >=0)
        notifyItemChanged(position)
```

And in your viewholder, check if the adapterPosition equals to selectedItemPosition. this way, when you change the selected item, the old selected item gets de-selected, and the new one gets selected.